# How to store public and private keys of kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA type with size 4096 in coredata instead of keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I have generated Public and Private keys using RSA4096 and not stored into keychain by setting kSecAttrIsPermanent to false.

Now I am trying to store SecKey into core data and I am not able to convert SecKey to NSData. Please suggest

```
let privateKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
    kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false as AnyObject,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag as String:"com.RSAKey.MyApp" as AnyObject
]

// public key parameters
let publicKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
    kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false as AnyObject,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag as String:"com.RSAKey.MyApp" as AnyObject
]

// global parameters for our key generation
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
    kSecAttrKeyType as String:          kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:    4096 as AnyObject,
    kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:       publicKeyParams as AnyObject,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:      privateKeyParams as AnyObject,
]

var pubKey, privKey: SecKey?
let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &pubKey, &privKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation()` to convert SecKey into Data.